# I am trying to delete a record in the database using mysql javascript API

Tags: javascript, mysql, variables

I am trying to delete a record from the database using javascript mysql API. I have create a table where I have listed my records from the database. I have added a delete button and a view details button. Now when I click the delete button. The delete button deletes the last row not the one which has the button that I have clicked. My view details button was just working fine until now it's doing the same. It views the last row's information instead the the row which contains the view button. This started happening when I added the delete button code. The code is below. Please help me understand what's going on.

HTML Code. I have edited and added the html code. A typical row below.

```
<tr class="record" id="record153">
<td>John Doe</td>
<td>11p</td>
<td>10</td>
<td>Cotton</td>
<td><p>Compound D: ranging from 464.29kg to  535.71kg.<br>  Ammonium nitrate: ranging from 223.88kg to 253.73kg.<br> Potasium nitrate: ranging from 0.00kg to 0.00kg.</p></td>
<td><button>View Detail</button><button>Delete</button></td>
</tr>
```

Javascript code

```
var historicalContent = document.querySelector('.historical-data');
    window.views.peek().style.display = "none";
    historicalContent.style.display = 'block';
    var backButton = document.querySelector('#back');
    backButton.style.display = 'block';
    var dashboard = document.querySelector("#dashboard");
    window.views.push(dashboard);
    window.views.push(historicalContent);

    var table = document.querySelector('.table-container table');
    let sql = `SELECT * FROM lab_results`;
    let labResultsCollection;
    //fire
    connection.query(sql, function (err, results, fields) {
        if (err) throw err;
        else {
            labResultsCollection = results;
            console.log(results);
            for (result of results) {
                let record = document.createElement('tr');
                record.className = 'record';
                record.id = 'record' + result.id;
                let farmerName = document.createElement('td');
                farmerName.innerText = result.name;
                let reference = document.createElement('td');
                reference.innerText = result.ref;
                let labNumber = document.createElement('td');
                labNumber.innerText = result.lab_number;
                let recommendations = document.createElement('td');
                let cropName = document.createElement('td');

                connection.query(`SELECT crop_id FROM crop_has_lab_results WHERE lab_results_id = ${result.id}`,
                    function (err, bresult, fields) {
                        if (err) {
                            throw err
                        } else {
                            //now get the id of the crop
                            crop_id = bresult[0].crop_id;
                            //fire
                            connection.query(`SELECT name FROM crop WHERE id = ${crop_id}`,
                                function (err, cresult, fields) {
                                    if (err) throw err;
                                    else {

                                        cropName.innerText = cresult[0].name;

                                    }
                                })
                        }
                    })

                connection.query(`SELECT recommendation_id FROM lab_results_has_recommendation WHERE lab_results_id = ${result.id}`,
                    function (err, bresult, fields) {
                        if (err) {
                            throw err
                        } else {
                            //now get the id of the crop
                            if (bresult.length > 0) {
                                console.log(bresult);
                                recommendation_id = bresult[0].recommendation_id;
                                //fire
                                connection.query(`SELECT text1,text2,text3 FROM recommendation WHERE id = ${recommendation_id}`,
                                    function (err, cresult, fields) {
                                        if (err) throw err;
                                        else {

                                            let str = `<p>${cresult[0].text1}.<br/> ${cresult[0].text2}.<br/> ${cresult[0].text3}.</p>`;
                                            recommendations.innerHTML = str;

                                        }
                                    })
                            }
                        }
                    })
                record.appendChild(farmerName);
                record.appendChild(reference);
                record.appendChild(labNumber);
                record.appendChild(cropName);
                record.appendChild(recommendations);
                let actions = document.createElement('td')
                let viewDetail = document.createElement('button');
                viewDetail.innerText = 'View Detail';
                let deleteRecord = document.createElement('button');
                deleteRecord.innerText = 'Delete';
                actions.appendChild(viewDetail);
                actions.appendChild(deleteRecord);
                record.appendChild(actions);



                deleteRecord.addEventListener('click', function () {
                    let xmysql = `DELETE FROM lab_results_has_recommendation WHERE lab_results_id = ${result.id}`;
                    let xmysql2 = `DELETE FROM crop_has_lab_results WHERE lab_results_id = ${result.id}`;
                    let xmysql3 = `DELETE FROM lab_results WHERE id = ${result.id}`;
                    console.log(xmysql, xmysql2, xmysql3);
                    connection.query(xmysql, function (err, bresult, fields) {
                        if (err) throw err;
                        else {
                            connection.query(xmysql2, function (err, cresult, fields) {
                                if (err) throw err;
                                else {
                                    connection.query(xmysql3, function (err, dresult, fields) {
                                        if (err) throw err;
                                        else {
                                            let record = document.getElementById(`record${result.id}`);
                                            console.log("Id of the removed", result.id);
                                            record.remove();
                                        }
                                    })
                                }
                            })

                        }
                    })
                })


                viewDetail.addEventListener('click', function () {
                    var detailPanel = document.querySelector('#detail-pane');
                    window.views.peek().style.display = 'none';
                    detailPanel.style.display = 'block';
                    detailPanel.innerHTML = '';
                    window.views.push(detailPanel);
                    let id = result.id;
                    let mysql = `SELECT * FROM lab_results WHERE id = ${id}`

                    connection.query(mysql, function (err, mresult, fields) {
                        if (err) {
                            throw err;
                        } else {
                            let myresult = mresult[0];
                            var name = document.createElement('h3');
                            name.innerText = myresult.name;
                            detailPanel.appendChild(name);
                            var lab_number = document.createElement('p');
                            lab_number.innerText = `Lab number: ${myresult.lab_number}`;
                            detailPanel.appendChild(lab_number);
                            var ref = document.createElement('p')
                            ref.innerText = `Reference: ${myresult.ref}`;
                            detailPanel.appendChild(ref);
                            var color = document.createElement('p');
                            color.innerText = `Color: ${myresult.color}`;
                            detailPanel.appendChild(color);
                            var texture = document.createElement('p');
                            texture.innerText = `Texture: ${myresult.texture}`;
                            detailPanel.appendChild(texture);
                            var pH = document.createElement('p');
                            pH.innerText = `pH: ${myresult.pH}`;
                            detailPanel.appendChild(pH);
                            var free_carbonate = document.createElement('p');
                            free_carbonate.innerText = `Free carbonate: ${myresult.free_carbonate}`;
                            detailPanel.appendChild(free_carbonate);
                            var conductivity = document.createElement('p');
                            conductivity.innerText = `Conductivity: ${myresult.conductivity}`;
                            detailPanel.appendChild(conductivity);
                            var nitrogen = document.createElement('p');
                            nitrogen.innerText = `Initial nitrogen ${myresult.nitrogen}`;
                            detailPanel.appendChild(nitrogen);
                            var nitrogen_after = document.createElement('p');
                            nitrogen_after.innerText = `Nitrogen after incubation ${myresult.m_nitrogen_init}`;
                            detailPanel.appendChild(nitrogen_after);
                            var phosphorus = document.createElement('p');
                            phosphorus.innerText = `Phosphorus: ${myresult.phosphorus}`;
                            detailPanel.appendChild(phosphorus);
                            var potasium = document.createElement('p');
                            potasium.innerText = `Potasium: ${myresult.potasium}`;
                            detailPanel.appendChild(potasium);
                            var calcium = document.createElement('p');
                            calcium.innerText = `Calcium: ${myresult.calcium}`;
                            detailPanel.appendChild(calcium);
                            var magnesium = document.createElement('p');
                            magnesium.innerText = `Magnesium: ${myresult.magnesium}`;
                            detailPanel.appendChild(magnesium);
                            var total_bases = document.createElement('p');
                            total_bases.innerText = `Total bases: ${myresult.total_bases}`;
                            detailPanel.appendChild(total_bases);

                            let mysql2 = `SELECT * FROM lab_results_has_recommendation WHERE lab_results_id = 
                                    ${myresult.id}`;
                            connection.query(mysql2, function (erra, mresult2, fields) {
                                if (err) throw err;
                                else {
                                    let myresult2 = mresult2[0];
                                    let mysql3 = `SELECT * FROM recommendation WHERE id = ${myresult2.recommendation_id}`;
                                    connection.query(mysql3, function (err, mresult3, fields) {
                                        if (err) throw err;
                                        else {
                                            let myresult3 = mresult3[0];
                                            let divider = document.createElement('hr');
                                            divider.width = '100%';
                                            detailPanel.appendChild(divider);
                                            let recommendationView = document.createElement('div');
                                            let recommendationHeading = document.createElement('h4');
                                            recommendationHeading.innerText = 'Recommendation';
                                            recommendationView.appendChild(recommendationHeading);

                                            var nitrogen2 = document.createElement('p');
                                            nitrogen2.innerText = `Nitrogen: from ${myresult3.nitrogen} `;
                                            recommendationView.appendChild(nitrogen2);
                                            var phosphorus2 = document.createElement('p');
                                            phosphorus2.innerText = `Phosphorus: from ${myresult3.phosphorus}`;
                                            recommendationView.appendChild(phosphorus2);
                                            var potasium2 = document.createElement('p');
                                            potasium2.innerText = `Potasium: from ${myresult3.potasium}`;
                                            recommendationView.appendChild(potasium2);
                                            var lime = document.createElement('p');
                                            lime.innerText = `Lime: from ${myresult3.lime}`;
                                            recommendationView.appendChild(lime);
                                            var text1 = document.createElement('p');
                                            var text2 = document.createElement('p');
                                            var text3 = document.createElement('p');
                                            text1.innerText = myresult3.text1;
                                            text2.innerText = myresult3.text2;
                                            text3.innerText = myresult3.text3;
                                            recommendationView.appendChild(text1);
                                            recommendationView.appendChild(text2);
                                            recommendationView.appendChild(text3);
                                            detailPanel.appendChild(recommendationView);


                                        }
                                    })
                                }
                            })

                        }
                })


            })
            table.appendChild(record);
```

Comment: where is result.id coming from? what is the value?

Comment: can you post the HTML part of the code?

Comment: I assume you have a delete button on each row? and also an ID on each row? you need to fetch the ID from the row and parse it down to the sql statement as where condition. If you add a your table and other JS, we can give more help.

Comment: @VaibhavSingh I have edited the code. The result.id is coming from the data that I have queried from the database

Comment: @Cyber I have added the other javascript code and html markup

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the line with `for (result of results) {` you don't declare `result` with `let` or `const` which means it will make the variable implicitely global.

You should instead write `for (const result of results) {` (`let` would technically work but it makes it even clearer that the result of that scope has not been changed at any point in time.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you are not passing the result id in your delete listener. It is being picked from the scope, which is the last row of the for loop. Thus your issue is expected behaviour.

You should read about [JS Closures](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_function_closures.asp) to know more about it.